# How to simulate a browser through modal-popup?

Tags: javascript, popup

As the title suggests I want to simulate a browser (or a windowed program) through a modal popup window on my site. It doesn't need to be draggable or resizable, I'm just having trouble making this "frame" around the popup window so you scroll the content and the top (with the closing "X" icon and the "program"-name) doesn't get scrolled as well.

Any suggestions how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to show a **popup** containing a **scrollable frame** with a **close button and title** section doesn't scroll?

You can create the popup using the html and css here ([working example](http://jsfiddle.net/bo9zzdp8/4/)). You can easily change the iframe to a normal content div if you want.

## html code

```
<div id="popup" style="display:none;">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="close">x</div>
        <div class="frame">
            <div class="title">Title</div>
            <iframe src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## css code

```
/* full screen dark overlay */
 .overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
/* full screen popup */
 .box {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
/* round black close button */
 .close {
    /* at the top right */
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 102;
    /* in front of the frame */
    /* round black */
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #000;
    color:#fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align:center;
}
/* contains the title and frame */
 .frame {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 100;
}
/* The title */
 .frame .title {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding:10px;
}
/* The iframe for your content */
 .frame iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    border: none;
}
```

## Advanced options

If you need more advanced options such as no scrolling of the background body, non full screen popup, center etc, you can checkout popup plugins. You can check my jquery plugin [GenericBox](http://danlevan.github.io/jquery.generic) for example code or there are a bunch of other plugins available for other options.